# Why both forward and reverse primer are added in asymmetric PCR?

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques, pcr

If the purpose of Asymmetric PCR is to amplify single targeted strand of dsDNA then instead of adding just one primer for targeted strand why do we add both forward and reverse primer? Upon addition of only one type of primer won't we will get linear amplification of that strand?

Comment: The other primer is at least 30 times less. I suppose this is done for amplifying the template to a certain extent. If you have a pure template (i.e. the exact length as the final product) of good enough concentration then the other primer is not required at all.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about it as I haven't done it personally and I couldn't find any material on this topic. So it is just a guess.